# Is it possible to map to a "fallback" Decodable using RxSwift and Moya?

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rx-cocoa, moya

I am using RxMoya for the network layer of my app and I'm having a case where the server can either send the expected response (let's say a `User`), or an error object, both with status code 200. For example:

```
{
  "name": "john doe",
  "username": "john_doe"
}
```

could be the expected response and

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 100,
    "message": "something went wrong™"
  }
}
```

could be the error.

The relevant part of the network adapter could look like this:

```
    return provider
        .rx
        .request(MultiTarget.target(target))
        .map(User.self)
        // if above fails, try:
        // .map(UserError.self)
        .asObservable()
```

Is there a way to firstly try and `.map(User.self)` and if that fails, try to `.map(UserError.self)` in the same chain of operations? In other words, could I provide an alternative mapping model using Rx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` to do that. Something like this:

```
    return provider
    .rx
    .request(MultiTarget.target(target))
    .flatMap { response -> Single<User> in
        if let responseType = try? response.map(User.self) {
            return Single.just(responseType)
        } else if let errorType = try? response.map(UserError.self) {
            return Single.error(errorType.error)
        } else {
            fatalError("⛔️ We don't know how to parse that!")
        }
     }
```

BTW, status code 200 to return an error is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed your answer. The problem is that I want to return a `Single.just(user)` in the first case and a `Single.error(errorMessage)` in the second. In your code, what does the line `if let user = User.self` do?

Comment: Ok, got it. Since you deserve the points, I'm editing your answer a bit before accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I thought `User.self` was optional and did the unwrap with the `if let`. But yes, you can return `Single.just(user)` and `Single.error` but the error should have an `Error` object and not a string. Also, if the return type of the `flatMap` is `Single<User>` you can type directly `.just(user)` and `.error(error)`